find variable Type with ANTLR
i used ANTLR to create lexer and parser for java8 grammar in python.
my goal is using python to save every variable type in a java code with that lexer and parser generated by ANTLR.
how can i get a type of Tokens generated by ANTLR?
i tried different ANTLR bulit-in methods, but it's came to nothing

Every ANTLR token has a text property and a type property. In Python, you can simply get them by calling .type on your token. If you want a more specific answer, post your code/grammar and explain what it is you're trying to do.
